# How do I resolve this error DependencyNotFoundError: Could not find dependency: 'redux' relative to '/src/App.js'?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here's the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reduxstore-o345hw

P.S. beginner

I tried installing the dependency but still not working. I'm using  react.js and redux.

Comment: That Sandbox doesn't seem to show an error. Apart from that, are you aware that you are using an outdated (pre-2019) style of Redux here that is much more code & error-prone? I would generally recommend reading [why Redux Toolkit is how to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and following the official Redux tutorial then: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts